# Sorting an array meanwhile entering values

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

i need to sort the array while entering values that means that while the user enters numbers the array needs to sort itself: what i did so far is this:

```
void MoveRight(int *a,int n, int startIndex)
{
    int j,temp;
    j=n-1;
    for(int i=startIndex;i<n;i++)
    {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
    }
}

void InsertionSort(int *a,int n)
{
    int i,number,j;
    printf("Enter %d numbers for the array\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&number);
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(number<a[j])
            {
                MoveRight(a,n,j);
                a[j]=number;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After entering: 1,3,2,4,5

The array i got was : -858993460,-858993460,-858993460,-858993460,-858993460

Comment: What is `a`? Post the call of `InsertionSort`

Comment: What are initial values in Array `a`? When you entered `1`, it will go in array only if any element in array is greater than 1. From your output, array contains `-858993460` which is less than `1` and hence no value was stored in array

Comment: You need to modify your algorithm of `InsertionSort`

Comment: Hint: `-858993460` or (0xCCCCCCCC in hexadecimal) is the value used for uninitialized automatic variables by Microsoft Visual Studio debug builds.

Comment: I think it's `j<i`?

Comment: Show a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Array is a poor data structure choice for this task.

Comment: If the inserted value is larger than any value in the array then no value is stored. You need to detect that condition and insert the value last in the array when it happens.

Comment: oh, so the reason is that i didn't put a condition for larger values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply the selection sort you should at first to enter all elements in the array.

These loops

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&number);
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(number<a[j])
        {
            MoveRight(a,n,j);
            a[j]=number;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

already result in undefined behavior because when `i` and `j` are equal to 0 then `a[j]` has indeterminate value. And moreover if the condition `number<a[j]`  is not evaluated to true then nothing will be added to the array.

Function `MoveRight` does not make sense because in the loop variable `j` is not changed.

```
j=n-1;
for(int i=startIndex;i<n;i++)
{
        temp = a[j];
        a[j]=a[i];
        a[i]=temp;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the task can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MoveRight( int *a, int n, int i )
{
    for ( ; n != i; --n ) a[n] = a[n-1];
}

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N];

    printf( "Enter %d numbers for the array: ", N );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int value;

        scanf( "%d", &value );

        int j = 0;
        while ( j < i && !( value < a[j] ) ) j++;

        MoveRight( a, i, j );
        a[j] = value;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
Enter 10 numbers for the array: 5 2 3 9 8 1 6 7 4 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Take into account that for large arrays it is much better to use the binary search instead of the sequential search to find the position where to insert the next value.

Comment: this is not what i meant. What i wanted is : while user enters each value the array needs to sort it self

Comment: @user6219654 And what does my program do?! Each value entered by the user is placed in the correct position in the array.

Comment: sorry, I thought i might be able to debug it in my head but i failed. After executing your code, i see that you are right :( . Thanks for the help

Comment: @user6219654 No problem. My function does the same as your function try to do.:)